# brew install glew did not resolve my <GL/glew.h> dependency issues

Tags: c++, glew

I'm using terminal on a Macintosh.

The commands to compile are basic:

```
g++ -c  String.cpp -o String.o
g++ -c  FileIO.cpp -o FileIO.o
g++ -c  AffineTransforms.cpp -o AffineTransforms.o
g++ -c  Node.cpp -o Node.o
g++ -c  Vertex.cpp -o Vertex.o
g++ -c  BasicObject.cpp -o BasicObject.o
g++ -c  Picture.cpp -o Picture.o
g++ -c  Window.cpp -o Window.o
Window.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
#include <GL/glew.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I used `brew install glew` as recommended and the issues have not been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You should include like this:

```
#include <glew.h>
```